# Get [NSDate date] with UTC time

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm developing an iOS 5.0+ app with latest SDK.

I have this code to get a date as string:

```
NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"ddMMyyyy HH:mm"];
NSDate* now = [NSDate date];
NSString* dateAsString = [formatter stringFromDate:now];
```

var `now` is `2013-11-20 10:59:21 CET` and `dateAsString` is `20112013 10:59` but I need to get this date with UTC time. Here in Spain, I think is -1 hour.

**How can I get [NSDate date] with UTC time?**

Comment: I didn't but plz look into timezone and locale

Comment: You *have* UTC time in the NSDate object.  If you bothered to search at all you'd find that NSDateFormatter assumes the local timezone unless you set it to UTC.

Comment: It's always hard to find a duplicate when you want to, but this question comes up weekly; daily at certain times of the year.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use `NSTimeZone`:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"ddMMyyyy HH:mm"];

// Add this part to your code
NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];
[formatter setTimeZone:timeZone];

NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSString *dateAsString = [formatter stringFromDate:now];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add timezone with your date formatter as

```
NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];
[formatter setTimeZone:timeZone];
```